# How to connect from one schema to another schema of same database automatically when running a .sql file?

Tags: sql

I am running a test.sql file from command prompt by connecting to the database named DB. The test.sql file contains DDL, DML statments in it.
The Schemas named A and B are used in the test.sql file.

First connection to the schema connect&&schema A was made. The DDL, DML statements for schema A got executed.

Next connect&&schema B was made in that same test.sql file. So the script at run time asks for the value of schema name B. After the connection to schema B then the DDL, DML statements for schema B will be executed.

Please suggest if I can connect automatically to schema B without entering the value of schema B name at run time when running the test.sql file.

Comment: Too vague, please include example SQL, that sufficiently demonstrate a concrete example of what you are trying to do and why it doesn't quite meet your requirements.

Comment: `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=schemaB`

Comment: Hi ,

The example SQL is

The test.sql file has the following

conn &&schema_A/&&schema_A_password@&&service_name

begin

for in () loop

end loop;

end;
/

conn &&schema_B/&&schema_B_password@&&service_name

begin

for in () loop 

end loop;

end;
/

The test.sql file at run time asks for schema B name. Please suggest if i can automatically connect to schema_B without entering value of schema_B name at run time while running the test.sql file.